# Windows Phone In App Purchasing - Cannot convert TValue to ProductListing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 app with in-app purchase capability. In order to retrieve my products I do this:

```
ListingInformation listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
foreach (var productListing in listing.ProductListings.Values)
{
    ...
}
```

where listing.ProductListings's type is as shown below
[image]

---

However, when I try to replace var with ProductListing, I get the following error
[image]
So I am unable to access my product information.

This is the product listing class:

```
public class ProductListing
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FormattedPrice { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Keywords { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code about that `ProductListing` type?

Comment: Are you really using the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.ProductListing class or did you create a class named ProductListing?

Comment: @heringer I am using the actual one. I got this code from a sample mock library provided by Microsoft

Comment: any chance to use the "var" declaration and print productListing.GetType().ToString() ?

Comment: @heringer I created a test project and yes the type is indeed ProductListing and contains all the right information. However when I try to cast it in code to a ProductListing type, the compiler issues the error 'Cannot cast expression of type 'TValue' to type 'ProductListing'.

Comment: Can you post a link the mock library/some more sources? Also, what do you mean by "I am unable to access my product information"? You should be perfectly fine with a 'var' as it has the correct type (it's simply syntactic sugar for compile-time type inference).

Comment: @M.Stramm if I leave it as 'var', the compiler doesn't interpret it as 'ProductListing', rather the var ends up being of type 'TValue' which I don't know what that is, and it has only 4 fields available for access (Equals,GetHashCode,GetType,ToString). The mock library is not really relevant, its meant for testing. my issue can replicated by creating a basic template WP8 project and try to list an app's products.

Comment: @Ramsay That is weird because TValue is merely the second generic parameter to the `IReadOnlyCollection<>`. My best guess is that it can't get a reference to the type for some reason. Are your assembly references correct?

Comment: @M.Stramm assembly references are the ones that come by default. Mainly '.NET for Windows Phone' and 'Windows Phone'. It shouldn't build if there was anything missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with Resharper 8.2. The new RC update seems to fix it.